# F# FS0001: This Expression was expected to have type figure, but her has type int*int

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I am currently working on a program that is supposed to take a 'figure' and move it along a vector. For this I have created the function 'move' which takes a 'figure' and a vector.
I am then trying to use pattern-matching to update the values of the figure.

```
type point = (int*int)
type figure =
 |Circle of point * int * string
 |Rectangle of point * point * string
 |Mix of figure * figure 

let circ = Circle((50,50),45,"Red")
let rect = Rectangle((40,40),(90,110),"Blue")
let figTest : figure = Mix(circ,rect)
```

I have the above types and the starting figure, 'figTest'.
I then call 'move figTest', but it gives the error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 'figure' but here has type 'int * int -> figure'.

```
let rec move figure (v:int*int) : figure= 
 let vx = fst v
 let vy = snd v
 
 match figure with
 | Circle ((cx,cy) , radius, colour) -> Circle(point(cx + vx, cy-vy), radius, colour)
 | Rectangle((x0,y0), (x1,y1), colour) -> Rectangle(point(x0 + vx, y0 + vy),point(x1 + vx, y1 + vy), colour)
 | Mix(f1,f2) ->
     let newCirc = move(f1)
     let newRect = move(f2)
     let newFig = Mix(newCirc, newRect)
     newFig
```

The error seems to occur when i give 'newFig' the new circle and rectangle, but I can't quite figure out what is wrong. I struggle quite a bit with these type errors in f# pretty often, so I thought I was getting the hang of it, but I just can't find the cause of this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very close to working, so don't get discouraged. There are two minor problems:

1. When you call `move` recursively, you have to pass `v` again. So `let newCirc = move f1 v` is correct instead of `let newCirc = move(f1)`. (Note that `newCirc` might not actually be a circle, so you might want to use a different variable name.)
2. Since `point` is just a synonym for `int * int`, it doesn't have its own constructor function. So `(cx + vx, cy-vy)` is correct instead of `point(cx + vx, cy-vy)`.

When I made these two changes, your code worked correctly for me. There are a number of other issues with your code that you might want to address, but those are the only two that are show-stoppers at this point.